# product of elements of the vector

Tags: r

I want to write a function that, given a vector v computes the product of all the entries in v. (There is a function in R that does this, but I want to write one myself.)

I tried however how can I get for product of any elements in a vector?

```
product <- function(v){
    out <- 1
    for(i in 1:length(v)){
       out <- out*v[i]
    }
    out
}
```

Comment: You code looks good and works for me. What do you get when you do try `product(c(1, 2, 3))`?

Comment: I get `6` with your code.  I also get `6` with `Reduce("*", as.list(c(1, 2, 3)))`

Comment: Yes thanks! but your code is what I wanted it works for any kind of elements.

Comment: Careful with your terminology! You wanted a function that takes *multiple arguments*. Elements are the individual items in a vector, arguments are the things you give to a function.

Comment: So Nu? What is the name of the function that does it? It would be the equivalent to `sum`. ...I found it. Is is `prod`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `...` as the argument to your function, you can pass it several objects or just one.  Inside the function, you can convert to a list and use `Reduce` to apply a function (`*`) recursively to the list.  If you combine `list`, `unlist` and `as.list` you can make this very general.  The following will work with a vector, or with 2 or more numbers, or a mixture of vectors and single numbers.

```
> product <- function(...) Reduce("*", as.list(unlist(list(...))))
> product(2, 7, 3)
[1] 42
> product(c(2, 7, 3))
[1] 42
> product(2, c(7, 3))
[1] 42
```

Comment: I'm probably missing a corner case or something but would `product <- function(...) Reduce("*", c(...))` do essentially the same thing?

Comment: I guess if there was list input instead of just vectors my approach wouldn't work but yours still does.

Comment: Don't know if anyone is still reading this, but why would `list`, then `unlist`-ing, and `as.list` again make this function more general??? Doesn't it just take a list, break it apart, and put it back into a list again?

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Recall` for tail recursion:

```
 prd2 <- function(x)
     if(length(x) == 2) { x[1] *x[-1] } else x[1] * Recall(x[-1])
 prd2(c(2,3,4))
#[1] 24
```